# How to integrate OAuth with Azure B2C in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have to integrate OAut, Azure AD B2C for my existing spring mvc application.
Appreciate any help on implementing the base.

Answer (score 0):

This sample to **[Java Spring MVC web app that authenticates users with Azure AD B2C](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-spring-tutorial/tree/main/1-Authentication/sign-in-b2c#project-initialization)** 
describes how to use [Azure AD B2C Spring Boot Starter client library for Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/java/api/overview/azure/spring-boot-starter-active-directory-b2c-readme?view=azure-java-stable) to sign in users into your Azure AD tenant . It also makes use of Spring Oauth2 Client and Spring Web boot starters.

You need to Register the app in azure ad b2c,
Add the ,dependencies required in your `pom.xml` file,
Add  the properties in `application.yml` using the values you created earlier in app registration.
You can follow further steps in detail  for registration according to [starter library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/main/sdk/spring/azure-spring-boot-starter-active-directory-b2c)

main **Reference:**

[GitHub - Azure-Samples -java-spring-tutorial](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-spring-tutorial)

Comment: The scenario is to use with Spring MVC and not with Springboot.
I appreciate your response!